# Why is the latest version of log4j provided by the CentOS mirrors are only up to version 1.2.17?

Tags: centos, log4j, redhat, rpm

In the CentOS version 7 rpm repositories I am only finding the most recent version of log4j 1.2.17. The vulnerability is suggesting a version 2.x I believe 2.15. I do find the 2.x versions on the apache site but those are not rpm based.

Comment: I should add I am talking about version CentOS 7.x

Comment: there are API breaking changes when migrating from 1.2.X to 2.X the client code would need adoptions to the changed version.

Answer (score 0):

There are different log4j frameworks.  The version for 1.2.17 is the latest for 1.x and they changed the framework name after version 2. I think you should try log4j2, log4J-api or log4J-core.

For example, there are different versions for Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.16.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.16.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```